# What are good books for grounding to study Parsonson's Advanced Mathematics texts?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, arithmetic

I noticed in the first exercise itself that one requires knowledge of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. What introductory books gives the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic? It'd be nice of the book also explained how to extract roots and find the highest common factors of big numbers alongside proofs of the basic geometric formulas-Pythagoras, surface area of a sphere, etc.

Comment: "Number Theory" by George E. Andrews proves it from the basis representation theorem. Finding large prime factors is a known hard problem and there are no general methods for finding them at this time.

Number theory and geometry are different subjects so it's unlikely you'll find a book with those other things in it that also proves the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Surface area of a sphere will show up in introductory calculus texts and the Pythagorean theorem has so many different proofs you're spoiled for choice. Just pick your favorite from the internet.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for a one-stop elementary maths textbook that does proof of easy theorems-for all the branches: arithmetic, algebra and geometry, e.g. laws of logarithms, remainder theorem, area of surfaces, volumes, divisibility,etc

Comment: I don't think any such text exists. It would be too large for a single volume and you'd have to break it up into multiple books.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What set of books then?

Comment: Number theory, geometry, calculus, analysis, and algebra texts will be required for a comprehensive treatment of those topics. Most of the work is related to volumes and areas since that requires integration, as does defining the real logarithm. Which you prefer is really a matter of taste but you have a lot to choose from.